# Drupal 8 account creation using email in contribution page

Tags: drupal, profile, contributions

Drupal 8 + CiviCRM.
I am using email registration module to register with email address only, not the username. I have added Drupal account creation form in contribution page from CiviCRM profile settings. But the problem is, in the contribution page the account creation form is showing username and password, not based on the email registration I installed in Drupal.
So my question is how can I make CiviCRM account creation from contribution page based on email registration module?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there isn't any such validation. If you have required registration ticked and requires email verification to activate account than add a js to hide the registration field and populate it when email address is entered